# Sympy solve returns empty set after adding positive restriction

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

when I'm running the following code in python and entering "x^2*y^2", "x*y" and so on, I'm getting an empty set:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, u = symbols('x y u',positive=True)
utility = sympify(input())
utility_function = Eq(u,utility)
solve(utility_function, y)
```

When I remove the positive = True, I'm getting solutions. How can I change my code that I only get the positive solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the same issue, but you should really pass the symbols defined as positive to the sympify function; if you don't, then symbols without assumptions will be created.

```py
sympify('v',locals={'v':var('v',positive=True)}).is_positive

u = var('u', positive=True)  # now part of locals()
sympify('u',locals=locals()).is_positive
```